# Google Indoor Map

Tags: google-maps, indoor-positioning-system

i am using  google indoor map but i want to open list of floor stores based on chosen floor from  level bar in google map.
how can i use  didChangeActiveLevel  function. Please help me

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     GMSMarker *marker=[[GMSMarker alloc]init];
     GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:28.566648700000000000
                                                        longitude:77.323976099999980000
                                                             zoom:18];

     self.mapView=[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds  camera:camera];
     self.mapView.myLocationEnabled=NO;
     self.mapView.settings.compassButton=YES;
     self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton=YES;
     [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];

       }
    - (void) didChangeActiveLevel:(GMSIndoorLevel *) level
       {
      NSLog(@"event fired");
      }
```

didChangeActiveLevel function not fired when i choose floor level from level bar

i have to show a list of store on that floor which are currently selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forget to connect delegate  so i face problem i solve the problem by adding given below code to my code

```
 self.mapView.delegate=self;
 self.mapView.IndoorDisplay.delegate=self;
```